# liquid error error on build on github blog

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, liquid

Error log

```
  Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 6): Unknown tag 'include_cached' in /_layouts/post.html
```

I am currently making a blog by forking this project at https://github.com/hydecorp/hydejack.
I've tried several methods for 2 days, but it doesn't work.  Locally it's fine, but when I build I get an error.
this is my project
https://github.com/JangHwanPark/JangHwanPark.github.io

I tried changing config.yml and layout to md file.  I also tried deleting the repository, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the way you do, the ["classic" way](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch) (as opposed to [using an action](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow)), GitHub uses a fixed configuration and a list of whitelisted plugins (visible [here](https://pages.github.com/versions/)). It really only includes the [`github-pages` gem](https://github.com/github/pages-gem), which includes all other dependencies. Your Gemfile is ignored for the build; among other things, this means the build uses Jekyll v3.9.2, and not v4.1 as in your Gemfile.

There are two approaches:

1. Stick with the "classic" experience. I recommend you make your local environment match that; the Gemfile simplifies to

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org"

   gem "github-pages", "~> 227", group: :jekyll_plugins
   ```

   Don't forget to run `bundle install` after you've updated the Gemfile so the lockfile gets updated, too.

   You'll have to update `_config.yml` to include your theme via the [`remote-theme` plugin](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme), and add the [`include-cache` plugin](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-include-cache) to the `plugins` list.

   This closely matches what the [docs for your theme](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-include-cache) also recommend.
2. Switch to a custom GitHub Actions flow to deploy your page. There is a [starter workflow for Jekyll](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/jekyll.yml); using that should get you most of the way there. You might still have to specify `remote_theme` in the config instead of `theme`, unless you copy the entire theme into your repo.

   Doing this lets you use any gems you want, and any Jekyll version you want.